# AdapterView received, when Item is clicked, hasn't the proper size

Tags: android, android-listview, onclicklistener, android-adapterview

In this activity I fill a ListView and I set a onClick method that it's called when we press one ListView item. This retrocalled method receives the AdapterView, that has not the same size that the real list (usually the last and the second last items don't exist on AdapterView).

In side each ListView item I have a RadioButton. I also have an onClick method for this RadioButton that is declared inside the getView() function.

When I press on a ListView item I get this error ( means that does not exist a child at that position)  (I get the same error by pressing a RadioButton instead of the item) :

```
02-16 11:54:05.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1175): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-16 11:54:05.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1175): Process: com.tfg.webquest, PID: 1175
02-16 11:54:05.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1175): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-16 11:54:05.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1175):     at com.tfg.webquest.QuestActivity$1.onItemClick(QuestActivity.java:126)
```

(This line: adapterView.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);  )

```
02-16 11:54:05.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1175):     at  android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
02-16 11:54:05.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1175):     at   android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
02-16 11:54:05.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1175):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2904)
02-16 11:54:05.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1175):     at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3638)
02-16 11:54:05.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1175):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
02-16 11:54:05.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1175):     at  android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-16 11:54:05.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1175):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-16 11:54:05.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1175):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-16 11:54:05.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1175):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-16 11:54:05.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1175):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-16 11:54:05.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1175):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-16 11:54:05.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1175):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-16 11:54:05.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1175):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

> 

```
    public class QuestActivity extends Activity {

    private ListView lv=null; //It contains the answer list 
    private String[] question;
    private ArrayList<AnswerModel> answerList = new ArrayList<AnswerModel>();
    MyCustomAdapter dataAdapter = null;
    private RadioButton lastRBListSelected;
    final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());    



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_quest);

        //Receive the parameters sent in the Intent of the previous activity (RegisterActivity)
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            question = extras.getStringArray("question");
        }else{
            Log.println(1,"QuestActivity.java, onCreate","Bundle recibido es nulo");
        }  

        //Fill the model and inflate the adapter
        displayListView();

        //Run the listener for detecting and answer chosen by pressing the listView
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.answer_list);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                adapterView.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox_answer);
                rb.setChecked(true);
                answerList.get(i).setSelected(true);

                if(lastItemListSelected!=-1){
                    answerList.get(lastItemListSelected).setSelected(false);
                    adapterView.getChildAt(lastItemListSelected).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(0x0106000d));
                    lastRBListSelected.setChecked(false);
                }

                lastItemListSelected=i;
                lastRBListSelected=rb;
            }
        });
    }   


    /**
     * Fill the model and create the adapter that fills the listView with the course data
     */
    private void displayListView() {
        //Fill the Model with the names
        for(int i=0;i<question.length;i++){
            AnswerModel answerModel = new AnswerModel(question[i],false);
            answerList.add(answerModel);
        }
        dataAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this,R.layout.answer,answerList);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.answer_list);
        lv.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
     }

    private class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<AnswerModel> {
        private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater; 
        private int mResourceId=0;
        private int mSelectedPosition=-1;

        public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<AnswerModel> answerList) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, answerList);
            mResourceId=textViewResourceId;
            mLayoutInflater=(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        private class ViewHolder {
            TextView name;
            RadioButton selected;
        }

        /**
          * It is retrocalled one time for each element of the list
          */
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder holder = null;
            View view = convertView;

            //Is the first time that getView is called
            if (view == null) {
                view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(mResourceId,parent,false);

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.selected = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox_answer);
                holder.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.code_answer);

                view.setTag(holder);

                holder.selected.setChecked(false);
                holder.selected.setTag(position);

                //Listener called when an answer is selected
                holder.selected.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {  
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {  

                            RadioButton rb;
                            rb = (RadioButton) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox_answer);

                            //Second, third... time we select a RB
                            if(position != mSelectedPosition && lastRBListSelected != null){
                                lv.getChildAt(lastItemListSelected).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(0x0106000d));
                                lastRBListSelected.setChecked(false);
                                answerList.get(lastItemListSelected).setSelected(false);
                                answerList.get(position).setSelected(true);
                                lv.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                                rb.setChecked(true);
                            }else{                      //First time we select a RB
                                rb = (RadioButton) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox_answer);
                                rb.setChecked(true);
                                answerList.get(position).setSelected(true);
                                ((ListView)findViewById(R.id.answer_list)).getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                            }

                            mSelectedPosition = position;
                            lastItemListSelected=position;                
                            lastRBListSelected=rb;
                        }
                });

            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            }

            //Set the values from the list into the adapter
            AnswerModel answerModel = answerList.get(position);
            holder.name.setText(answerModel.getName());
            holder.selected.setChecked(answerModel.isSelected());//
            holder.selected.setTag(answerModel);//

            return view;

        }
    }
}
```

This is the XML activity file (fragment_quest.xml):

> 

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/webquest_background"
    tools:context="com.tfg.webquest.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" 
    android:weightSum="23" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/countdown_quest"
            android:padding="5sp"
            android:textSize="23sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/main_center13"
            style="@style/entry_style"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_weight="18"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="5"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <ScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fillViewport="true"
                    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset" >
                    <TextView android:id="@+id/quest_question_text"
                        android:padding="5sp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/rectangle_quest"
                        style="@style/entry_style"/>
                </ScrollView>
            </RelativeLayout>   

</LinearLayout>
```

The XML file of each ListView item (answer.xml):

> 

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="6dip" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/checkBox_answer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/code_answer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:maxLines="10" 
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkBox_answer" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you for your time.

(Some elements have been simplified, can be some undefined references on the shown code)

Comment: Replace `adapterView.getChildAt(i)` by `view`